# Qt uploading texture thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, opengl, qglwidget

I am using a QGLWidget for displaying a live Image Stream. Since uploading textures is an expensive operation I would like to avoid doing this on the GUI Thread. I have read here `http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/06/03/threaded-opengl-in-4-8/` that it is possible to do this in from a different thread. Could anyone provide a short example how to do so? I am uncertain how to share the GL Context and how to make sure that there is no race condition.

This is what i currently have:

.h:

```
class ImageDisplay : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ImageDisplay(QWidget* parent = 0);
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);

private:
    QRectF plane;
    GLuint texID;

public slots:
    void sl_update(spImageHolder_t _myImageShPtr);
};
```

.cpp:

```
ImageDisplay::ImageDisplay(QWidget *parent)
    : QGLWidget(parent)
    , plane(QPointF(0,1),QSizeF(1,1))
{
    QImage initImg(400,300,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    resize(initImg.size());
    makeCurrent();
    texID = bindTexture ( initImg, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE, QGLContext::NoBindOption );
}

void ImageDisplay::paintGL()
{
    makeCurrent();
    drawTexture ( plane, texID, GL_TEXTURE_2D );
}
void ImageDisplay::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport (0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1,0,1,-1,1);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void ImageDisplay::sl_update(spImageHolder_t _myImageShPtr) //slot
{
    QImage * imgPtr = _myImageShPtr->getImagePtr();
    if (NULLPTR != imgPtr)
    {
        deleteTexture(texID);
        texID = bindTexture( *imgPtr, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE, QGLContext::NoBindOption );
    }
    updateGL();
}
```

Comment: Texture data uploads are not extremely expensive. But creating a new texture object. If you just want the texture image use glTexSubImage, keeping the old texture in place.